# Add value to sheet name on new workbook based on InputBox

Tags: vba, excel

This is what I have got so far:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateNewBookWithDaysInMonthSheets()
Dim WS As Worksheet, WB As Workbook
Dim MonthX As Date, Control As Variant, DaysInMonth As Byte, i As Byte

    'create input box
Control = InputBox("Create new FTE workbook for period:", "New FTE", "mm/yyyy")
If IsDate(Control) Then
    'Create sheets based on days in selected month
    MonthX = CDate(Control)
    DaysInMonth = Day(DateSerial(Year(MonthX), Month(MonthX) + 1, 0))
    Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = DaysInMonth
    Set WB = Workbooks.Add

    i = 1
    For Each WS In WB.Sheets
        WS.Name = i
        i = i + 1

        WB.SaveAs Filename:="FTE_" & Control & ".xlsm"

            'set default workbook count back to 3
            Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 3
    Next

Else
MsgBox "No period set"


End If

Set WS = Sheets.Add(Before:=Sheets("1"))
WS.Name = "Total for "


End Sub
```

My question would now be, how to add the "mm/yyyy" typed into the InputBox to the sheet name "Total for "? So that it would be e.g. "Total for 9/2015".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
WS.Name = "Total for " & replace(Control,"/",".")
```

This will concatenate the value typed into the InputBox to the end of the "Total for " string.

Note: You can't have more than 1 worksheet with the same name, so you may may want to add your value for i to the end like this

```
WS.Name = "Total for " & replace(Control,"/",".") & i
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jiminy.
It's good that you reminded me of that, as I did try it but unfortunately my value for control is mm/yyyy and apparently "/" doesn't cut for sheet name characters.

So many error messages for one day that I only now properly registered what it says.

So actually the issue would now be to set the Control value from e.g. "09/2015" to "Sep 2015" and then add it to the WS.Name = "Total for ".

Comment: I've edited my answer to use a "." instead of a "/". This is acceptable as a worksheet name. You could use "-" if you prefer. It saves converting the month to text

Comment: No problem, it's also worth looking into the MONTHNAME Function